# Map and access related key value pairs from python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, regex, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a Python dictionary as follows:

```
ip_dict = {
    "Policy general commercial general liability for the individual": [
        (("x1", "y1"), ("w1", "h1")),
        (("x2", "y2"), ("w2", "h2")),
        (("x3", "y3"), ("w3", "h3")),
        (("x4", "y4"), ("w4", "h4")),
        (("x5", "y5"), ("w5", "h5")),
        (("x6", "y6"), ("w6", "h6")),
        (("x7", "y7"), ("w7", "h7")),
        (("x8", "y8"), ("w8", "h8"))
    ]
}
```

The keys are words and the values are a list of tuples where, each element of the list represents the coordinates of the corresponding word. So the coordinates of `Policy` are `(("x1", "y1"), ("w1", "h1"))`, coordinates of `general` are `(("x2", "y2"), ("w2", "h2"))` and so on.

Now I want to search for particular phrases from the key of the dictionary using `re.search` and if a match is found then extract those phrases (from the key) and their corresponding coordinates (from the values) and store in a new dictionary. So if I have a phrase such as `commercial general liability` then the output dictionary would be as follows:

```
op_dict = {'commercial general liability': [(('x3', 'y3'), ('w3', 'h3')), (('x4', 'y4'), ('w4', 'h4')), (('x5', 'y5'), ('w5', 'h5'))]}
```

I have written the following logic but it is not working for the values:

```
    import re
    
    ip_dict = {
    "Policy general commercial general liability for the individual": [
        (("x1", "y1"), ("w1", "h1")),
        (("x2", "y2"), ("w2", "h2")),
        (("x3", "y3"), ("w3", "h3")),
        (("x4", "y4"), ("w4", "h4")),
        (("x5", "y5"), ("w5", "h5")),
        (("x6", "y6"), ("w6", "h6")),
        (("x7", "y7"), ("w7", "h7")),
        (("x8", "y8"), ("w8", "h8"))
    ]
}
    
    op_dict = {}
    
    # Search for the key containing "commercial general liability"
    for key in ip_dict.keys():
        if re.search(r"commercial.?\s.?general.?\s.?liability", key, flags = re.DOTALL):
            op_dict["commercial general liability"] = ip_dict[key]
            break
    
    print(op_dict)
    #OUTPUT
    {'commercial general liability': [(('x1', 'y1'), ('w1', 'h1')), (('x2', 'y2'), ('w2', 'h2')), (('x3', 'y3'), ('w3', 'h3')), (('x4', 'y4'), ('w4', 'h4')), (('x5', 'y5'), ('w5', 'h5')), (('x6', 'y6'), ('w6', 'h6')), (('x7', 'y7'), ('w7', 'h7')), (('x8', 'y8'), ('w8', 'h8'))]}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you have a duplicate word present? For example in the above case, 
 the word `general` is present twice. Which `general` do you want extracted?

Comment: @spectre as shown only those words and their corresponding coordinates should be extracted which are present in the keyphrase. So in the above case,the `general` coming after `commercial` should be extracted.

Comment: But what if you do `re.search(r"general")` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird That won't work as re.search() will return all the matched. Now how do I differentiate which match I want?

Comment: If you use re.findall, you will get a list as the return value. Then from that list you can pick which one you want.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That is exactly the issue. Since a word can occur multiple times in the search, how do I differentiate which word I want? This will be an automated solution, so I cannot sit there and do this manually!